# How can I find information about the package management software in the linux (unix) systems, in particular in cloud?

Tags: command-line, package-management, cloud

Sometimes when I log on to a system via SSH (for example to the same server), I have such privileges that there can install some software, but to do that I need to know how package management software is in the system.

Is there a way to quickly find it out?

In particular, for me `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux cloud 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How package management system can be here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the easiest way (at least to me) would be to simply check which package manager is installed.

It is not a wild guess to assume you are either using `apt` or `yum` (Debian based or Red Hat based package managers).

So, if you try:

```
which apt
/usr/bin/apt
```

You see that `apt` is installed. If you try:

```
which yum
<no output>
```

Or:

```
which pacman
<no output>
```

Then you do **not** have `yum`, or `pacman` in other words; for a case like this, use `apt`!

If you have none of the above, you will have to find out first of all which distribution you are using. Try this command:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

Based on the output above you can do a simple online search for the package manager for said distribution.